# set environment variables calling script file

Tags: unix, variables, environment, setting

I have a requirement where I have to set environment variables calling a script file eg:`set_env.sh`.
set_env.sh contains all the environment variables.

```
export SCRIPT_DIR=/e/scripts/
...
```

when I call the set_env.sh from my code the variables are available in that file itself. They are not available in file where I have called the script.

What should be done so that environment variables can be retained and can be used in file which calls set_env.sh.

---

Using `. set_env.sh` works - thanks.

Some related links with explanation:

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#SOURCEREF
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-export-environment-variable-from-a-bash-script-344057/

Answer (score 4):

You need to do

```
. set_env.sh
```

This runs `set_env.sh` in your current shell, rather than starting a new one.

Comment: Note that the shell searches for the file using the locations in $PATH, and also that the file to be 'dotted' ('sourced' is the alternative name since Bash - and C shell - use the command 'source' as an alternative to dot; the C shell only supports 'source', but Bash supports both) does not have to be executable; it is sufficient if it is readable.